# How to implement gradual startup/shutdown signals in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a compressor model, and I would like to control the startup and shutdown of it.

- When the control signal (K) is 1, that indicates on mode, when it is 0, that indicates off mode
- The control signal instantaneously goes from 1 to 0, indicating that shutdown has been initiated.
- Upon shutdown initiation, I would like the output of the compressor to *gradually* reduce to zero. For instance, if the user specifies that the compressor takes 20 seconds to shutdown, the signal should ramp down from 1 to 0 in 20 seconds.
- Similarly, upon startup initiation, the reverse should happen and the compressor output should go from 0 to 1 in 20 seconds.

For example, startup initiated at 20s, shutdown initiated at 70s:
[image: Compressor Startup/Shutdown Example]

What would be a computationally efficient way of doing this?

I thought maybe the Ramp + Saturation combination gives me a way of having my signal ramp up or down. Unfortunately, the ramp Start Time cannot be controlled adequately. Something like this, which I thought might work:

[image: Nope. Didn't work]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Rate Limiter](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/ratelimiter.html) block in conjunction with your "control signal"?

Comment: I didn't know about the block, however, it seems that it only works if my sample times are continuous. Since I'm using variable step solvers, this makes Simulink unhappy.

Comment: ?? You can, and probably should, use continuous sample times with variable-step solvers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the reapating sequence block in simulink.

you can define the sequence of the values you r signal is required to attain at each time instants. 
explore this option!

Comment: That doesn't work because the repeating sequence needs a fixed period. In this specific instance, the shutdown and startup are controlled by temperature, and therefore, don't happen after fixed periods of time.